# Python hugging face warning

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

my code is working but I am getting this warning and how can I avoid it

```
All model checkpoint layers were used when initializing TFRobertaForSequenceClassification.

All the layers of TFRobertaForSequenceClassification were initialized from the model checkpoint at arpanghoshal/EmoRoBERTa.
If your task is similar to the task the model of the checkpoint was trained on, you can already use TFRobertaForSequenceClassification for predictions without further training.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can manage the warnings with the [logging](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/logging) utility introduced in version 3.1.0:

```
from transformers import logging

logging.set_verbosity_warning()
```

Comment: Still getting that message

Comment: You actually want to set the log level to error: `logging.set_verbosity_error()`. @Gyanesh

Answer (score 0):

The code below suppresses warning messages:

```
from transformers.utils import logging
logging.set_verbosity_error()
```